# showing condition number of a matrix is the square root of $A^\top A$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} : m > n, A$ has full rank, I want to show that $k(A^\top A) = k(A)^2$, is there a way to do so purely from $k(A)=norm(A) norm(A^\dagger)$?

Recall that $A^\dagger = (A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top$

Comment: I changed the transpose from `^T` to `^\top`.

Comment: @ja72 Cheers, man! Learning new LaTeX is always good :)

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true in general only for the spectral norm (as far as I know), so you cannot show it by using only some simple facts about norms and pseudoinverses without going into details related to the spectral norm. These details are: for any real matrix $X$, $\|X\|_2^2=\rho(X^TX)=\rho(XX^T)$ and, if $X$ is square and symmetric, $\|X\|_2=\rho(X)$.

First,
$$
\|A^TA\|_2=\rho(A^TA)=\|A\|_2^2.
$$
Next,
$$
\|A^{\dagger}\|_2^2=\rho[A^\dagger(A^\dagger)^T]=\rho[(A^TA)^{-1}(A^TA)(A^TA)^{-1}]=\rho[(A^TA)^{-1}]=\|(A^TA)^{-1}\|_2.
$$