# Condition number of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that: $$cond_2(A^TA)={cond_2(A)}^2$$

The only thing that i know is that $||A||_2=max[\sqrt{\lambda} \in \Bbb R|\lambda \ is\ an\ eigenvalue\ of \ A^TA ]$
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Also [Condition number of $A^TA$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1351616)

Comment: Also [showing condition number of a matrix is the square root of $A^\top A$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1220000)